# Problemas com Data Grid wpf

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wpf, xaml

Boa noite.
Estou desenvolvendo um projeto porem estou com problemas, utilizo uma lista que esta sendo gerada com os dados do meu banco (entity para a conexão), quero povoar um data grid porem não quero que todos os campos do meu objeto apareça, como devo prosseguir? já tentei dgProdutos.Columns.Remove mais não consegui utilizar.

classe correspondente ao objeto produtos

```
class Produto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public int Quantidade { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public DateTime Validade { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProdutosParaProcedimentos> ListaProdutoProcedimento { get; set; }

    public Produto()
    {
    }
}
```

Classe que pega os dados do banco (ps sei que devo usar o try)

```
class ProdutoViewModel
{
    public static List<Produto> ExibirProdutos()
    {
        using (ConsultorioContext ctx = new ConsultorioContext())
        {
            var teste = ctx.Produtos.ToList();
            return teste;
        }      
    }
}
```

Classe xaml.cs da minha view

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dgProdutos.ItemsSource = ProdutoViewModel.ExibirProdutos();
    }
}
```

quero retirar ListaProdutoProcedimento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se não pode apagar esconda. Modifique a propriedade [`Visibility`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.visibility?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Controls_DataGridColumn_Visibility), da coluna que não quer exibir, para [`Visibility.Collapsed`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.visibility?view=netframework-4.7.2).

```
dgProdutos.Columns[/*coloque aqui o indice da coluna*/].Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Caso possua a intensão futura de exibir essa coluna é melhor usar `Visibility.Hidden` pois assim a UI reserva recursos para uma possível exibição

Comment: Perfeito, Muito obrigado